# Adding banner to homepage issue

Tags: magento-1.9

My problem is that i uploaded an image in the cms/banner/layout and it did not show on the homepage. This is the design from the homepage:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
       <action method="addPriceBlockType">
             <type>bundle</type>
             <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
             <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
       </action>
       <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
       <action method="setProductsCount"><count>6</count></action> 
</block>
</reference>
```

This is what is the generated html:

```
<a class="sama_banners_container" style="background-image:url('http://hoesjesoutletlocal.in2itive.ro/media/misc/image/cache/800xC:\xampp\htdocs\hoesjesoutlet\media\banner\image/d/s/dsc_0016-copy2-1024x592.jpg'); 
    height:380px;" href="">
    <!--span class="sama_banners_title">.</span-->
    <span class="sama_banners_description">test</span>
</a>
```

What am i missing ?

This is the code which generates the html:

```
<?php

    $banner = $this->getBanner();

    if ((int)$banner->getId()):
        $width = ((int)$banner->getWidth()) ? $banner->getWidth() : '' ;
        $height = ((int)$banner->getHeight()) ? $banner->getHeight() : '' ;
    ?>

    <a class="sama_banners_container" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $this->helper('sama_imageresize/image')->run($banner->getImage())->resize($width);?>'); 
        height:<?php echo $height?>px;" href="<?php echo $banner->getVar3();?>">
        <!--span class="sama_banners_title"><?php echo $banner->getTitle();?></span-->
        <span class="sama_banners_description"><?php echo $banner->getDescription();?></span>
    </a>
    <?php endif;?>
```

This is the block parts:

```
<block type="core/template" name="top_banners" before="-" template="homepage/topbanners.phtml">
                <block type="sama_banners/banner" name="homepage_banner" before="-" template="sama_banners/banner.phtml">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><id>homepage_large</id></action>
                </block>
                <block type="sama_banners/banner" name="homepage_small_1" before="-" template="sama_banners/banner.phtml">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><id>homepage_small_1</id></action>
                </block>
                <block type="sama_banners/banner" name="homepage_small_2" before="-" template="sama_banners/banner.phtml">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><id>homepage_small_2</id></action>
                </block>
                <block type="sama_banners/banner" name="homepage_small_3" before="-" template="sama_banners/banner.phtml">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><id>homepage_small_3</id></action>
                </block>
            </block>
```

Comment: How did you generate the code? The background image seems to point to a local file on your computer

Comment: I created a virtual host on my local server. I receveid the project as you see. I did not modify the code

Comment: The image url is :
"http://hoesjesoutletlocal.in2itive.ro/media/misc/image/cache/800xC:\xampp\htdocs\hoesjesoutlet\media\banner\image/d/s/dsc_0016-copy2-1024x592.jpg"

Seems wrong

Comment: I know this is wrong but this is what is generated. How do  i change the code in php  to make this works ?

Comment: My quess this is the wrong part: <?php echo $this->helper('sama_imageresize/image')->run($banner->getImage())->resize($width);?>.  But i do not know what is wrong with that line of code

Comment: How do you specify $banner->getImage() ? Do you have to upload an image or just put an URL?

Comment: I have to upload an image in the cms/banners....

Comment: Is it a custom module? I guess that the upload is not done correctly

Comment: no no it is not a module, it is from magento itself

Comment: Helper "sama_imageresize" is a custom helper, it seems to come with a custom module probably called "sama_banners"